# Multiple dropzones with different functionalities

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to have more than one "type" of drop zone on a page while using drag and drop upload?  For example, if I have one drop zone that will trigger a file upload when a file is dropped on it, and another that causes an alert saying "wrong dropzone!" to pop up.

It seems like there's a single drop event in html5 that's called, irrespective of which drop zone the user is interacting with.

I've tried using jQuery to come up with some solution -- for example, checking which div the mouse is hovering over immediately after the drop event is triggered, but it didn't work very well when I tested it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the problem is - but what you can have as many drop targets as you would like.  You need to create two elements, and listen for their dragover, dragenter and drop events.  You need to cancel the first two if you want to accept the drop, and handle the drop to do something with it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kw1unn7x/)

```
var dz1 = document.getElementById("dz1");
var dz2 = document.getElementById("dz2");

dz1.addEventListener("dragenter", cancelEvent);
dz2.addEventListener("dragenter", cancelEvent);
dz1.addEventListener("dragover", cancelEvent);
dz2.addEventListener("dragover", cancelEvent);

dz1.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    alert("You dropped on One");
    cancelEvent(e);
});

dz2.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    alert("You dropped on Two");
    cancelEvent(e);
});
```